# Google Hangouts Stuck and Unable to Sign in

Tags: google-chrome, google-hangouts

So, my Chrome Hangouts extension seems to be stuck trying to sign me in to an account, but I can't try signing into another account.

All I get is a message saying:

> **Unable to sign in**
>   This Hangouts feature has not been enabled for your account. You may chat in Gmail and make video calls from Gmail, Google+ and Google Calendar.

There are no settings or buttons I can use to change accounts.

I've tried uninstalling it, restarting my browser, restarting my computer, all to no avail. Any idea what I can do to reset this and sign into my proper account?

Comment: I would need more info. Are you on a company account or personal account?

Comment: It's a personal account. I'd post a photo, but I don't have enough reputation to do that =/

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58549/this-hangouts-feature-has-not-been-enabled-for-your-account

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved it!

Go into Privacy in Google Chrome's settings.  Clear your browser data. It looks like it had cached the wrong authentication key for me.

Comment: 10x, this helped me, too :)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help me, still searching for an answer.

Comment: This worked thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you need to reset Synced Data

https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync

click Reset Sync Data at the bottom.

Note:  You will lose synced data, unless that data is currently on your computer(you didn't clear history)

Comment: +10 This is excellent man, without losing my browser cache. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, however clearing cache did not solve it for me. Here's what I had to do,

1. Open a Chrome browser.
2. In the top right next to the minimize button, you should see a small box with your name in it. If you see a yellow caution flag, then you need to sign in again. This fixed my problem.

I see that this is a common issue, but not many people seem to know how to solve it, including Google. Or at least they're not being very generous with this knowledge. I digress, hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin.google.com:

Apps > Google Apps > Google Talk/Hangouts > Advanced Settings

- Hangouts chat only
- Hangouts chat or Google Talk
- Google Talk only

Choose the first or second option. Google Talk is only for chatting inside Gmail and such. Hangouts on the other hand offers the web app, as well as mobile.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, but this helped solve my issue. I suggested an edit since the question doesn't address Google Apps For Work editions of Hangouts.

Comment: This was it for me