# Persistent sign-in button in Google Hangouts Chrome extension; unable to log-in and use the app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-hangouts

A few weeks ago, I removed and re-installed the Hangouts extension for Google Chrome, and ever since, I have been unable to sign back in. Whenever I press the blue sign-in button in the extension's view tab, I am redirected to a Google sign-in page, but after signing in, I am redirected back to the blue sign-in button in the extension's view tab (???). The following attempted solutions do not work:

- [Signing in and out of my Chrome browser](https://superuser.com/questions/883300/hangouts-on-windows-7-doesnt-sign-in)
- [Clearing my browser cache](https://superuser.com/questions/719049/google-hangouts-stuck-and-unable-to-sign-in)
- Removing the extension and reinstalling

Note that this is a personal--not a Google Apps for Business--account.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more tinkering in the Chrome settings GUI, I figured out that the issue was caused by the fact that I block all third-party cookies in my browser (I had assumed that this setting wouldn't apply to Google-made apps like Hangouts). To solve the problem, I went to `Settings > Advanced Settings > Manage Content > Manage Cookie Exceptions` then added `hangouts.google.com` and `talkgadget.google.com` to the exceptions list.