# Contacts list tab in the Hangouts extension for Chrome is completely blank

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-hangouts

More Chrome extension drama: All of the sudden, the contacts list tab in the Hangouts extension for Chrome is completely blank, rendering the app unuseable. This just started happening today. The Hangouts support forum doesn't offer any solutions (for the time being). I'm using Windows 7 + Chrome browser: Version 45.0.2454.85 m (64-bit)

Tried to diagnose the problem via the developer console, and found this head-scratcher:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: preloadResources is not defined
```

Comment: I've got that message, too. My Hangouts works but won't make any notification (ringing or texts) sounds. This is true in Firefox and Chrome in 64 bit Windows 8.1.

Comment: @JimHunziker the problem solved itself after logging in and out of my Google account via Chrome and logging back in, then clearing my cache. The problem still persists occasionally, but closing and relaunching my browser seems to do the trick. Also, make sure you've got exceptions in place in case you're blocking 3rd party cookies: http://superuser.com/questions/970785/persistent-sign-in-button-in-google-hangouts-chrome-extension-unable-to-log-in/970850#970850